# Sitecore solr search configuration

Tags: solr, sitecore

We are migrating from lucene search component to solr Search component in sitecore, Some basic configurations are done but still we receive below error:

Method not found: 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.ProviderIndexSearchConfiguration Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration()'.

Comment: I'm assuming that you installed the SOLR Support Package also as well as the config changes?

Comment: Have you disabled lucene index configurations?

Comment: Yes i got package, only dlls were used.yes i have disabled them and enabled solr configs.

Comment: Also posted here - https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/11/t/1300

Answer (score 0):

Check, that the databases and paths that are referred to by the index configs (in each core) match the names and paths in your build.

It looks like Sitecore is trying to find the index that covers a particular item but is unable to locate one.

Either that, or the whole config is missing, in which case you have some SOLR config files disabled, or with a file attribute of Hidden, and they aren't being loaded.

Check /sitecore/admin/showConfig.aspx